# GPUImage: blending two images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing, gpuimage

I was using GPUImage framework (some old version) to blend two images (adding border overlay to a certain image).
After I have updated to latest framework version, after applying such a blend, I get an empty black image.

I'm using next method:

```
- (void)addBorder {
    if (currentBorder != kBorderInitialValue) {
        GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
        GPUImagePicture *imageToProcess = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:self.imageToWorkWithView.image];
        GPUImagePicture *border = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:self.imageBorder];

        blendFilter.mix = 1.0f;
        [imageToProcess addTarget:blendFilter];
        [border addTarget:blendFilter];

        [imageToProcess processImage];
        self.imageToWorkWithView.image = [blendFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];

        [blendFilter release];
        [imageToProcess release];
        [border release];
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're forgetting to process the border image. After `[imageToProcess processImage]`, add the line:

```
[border processImage];
```

For a two images being input into a blend, you have to use `-processImage` on both after they have been added to the blend filter. I changed the way that the blend filter works in order to fix some bugs, and this is how you need to do things now.

Comment: @BradLarson: Brad, can I add more than two pictures to blend filer in order to create the multiply effect? I have multiple layers and one background. I'd like to create sme nice effect using more than two [layer 1 and background layer]. Thanks!

Comment: hello, is there any resource on how to use `GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter` with realtime `GPUImageStillCamera` which doesn't have `processImage` method? I've asked a question about my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384813/gpuimagealphablendfilter-realtime-processing-from-gpuimagestillcamera-source

Comment: `imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput` giving error with latest guimage and ios8.  I have also used `imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:0` but still giving error.

Comment: @RahulRD I don't think there's any such thing as `imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput` anymore. I'm also getting a crash using the code from this answer. How did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 7):

This is the code I'm currently using for merging two images with GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter.

```
GPUImagePicture *mainPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
GPUImagePicture *topPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:blurredImage];

GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
[blendFilter setMix:0.5];

[mainPicture addTarget:blendFilter];
[topPicture addTarget:blendFilter];

[blendFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
[mainPicture processImage];
[topPicture processImage];

UIImage * mergedImage = [blendFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```