# How to set the correct scale factor for GPUImage filters and retina displays?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I am trying a GPUImage [filter from this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608332/gpuimage-blending-two-images) on a iPad with retina display.

The final image appears 2x larger than necessary. I think I have to set the correct size or scale factor, but how?

```
- (void)addBorder {
    if (currentBorder != kBorderInitialValue) {
        GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
        GPUImagePicture *imageToProcess = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:self.imageToWorkWithView.image];
        GPUImagePicture *border = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:self.imageBorder];

        blendFilter.mix = 1.0f;
        [imageToProcess addTarget:blendFilter];
        [border addTarget:blendFilter];

        [imageToProcess processImage];
        [border processImage];
        self.imageToWorkWithView.image = [blendFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];

        [blendFilter release];
        [imageToProcess release];
        [border release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[blendFilter forceProcessingAtSize:]` to set the output size of a GPUImageFilter directly.

Comment: Tried and works, but you end up with a low resolution image. It is fine with a UIImage scale of 1 but not retina quality.

Comment: Hm... are `imageToProcess` and `border` the same size?

Comment: Yes, same saze. Though the scale property of their UIImage is 2. The problem comes from GPUImageOutput where it creates the output UIImage without a correct scale factor (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, though it is a hack.

In GPUImageOutput, add:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)imageOrientation scale:(CGFloat)scale { // Added by Franz
    CGImageRef cgImageFromBytes = [self newCGImageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:imageOrientation];
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImageFromBytes scale:scale orientation:imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(cgImageFromBytes);

    return finalImage;
}
- (UIImage *)imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)imageOrientation;
{
    return [self imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:imageOrientation scale:1];
}
```

Then you are able to obtain an image for retina display with specified scale factor. Usage example:

```
UIImage *filteredImage = [filter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:sourceImage.imageOrientation scale:sourceImage.scale];
```

I can imagine that there is a simpler way.