# GPUImageSubtractBlendFilter two images using GPUImage framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, gpuimage

I'm trying to subtract two images using GPUImage framework. I think the correct way is to use GPUImageSubtractBlendFilter. I have an array of UIImages and am performing the following code to subtract both the images.

```
GPUImageSubtractBlendFilter *subFilter = [[GPUImageSubtractBlendFilter alloc] init];
GPUImagePicture *img1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:0]];
GPUImagePicture *img2 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:1]];

//consider modifications to filter possibly?

[img1 addTarget:subFilter];
[img2 addTarget:subFilter];

[img1 processImage];
[img2 processImage];
CGImageRef processedImage = [subFilter newCGImageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

I am also getting the following error output in console:

```
libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 627 (appName) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)
*** Assertion failure in -
GPUImage-master/framework/Source/GPUImageFramebuffer.m:156
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error at CVPixelBufferCreate -6661'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x186aa2fd8 0x185504538 0x186aa2eac 0x18753a710 0x1001b519c 0x1001b87dc 0x1001b4e40 0x1001b4858 0x1001b75b4 0x1001b87dc 0x1001b72e8 0x1001d5bd0 0x1001d4898 0x1001d6784 0x1001c5e4c 0x100311a50 0x100311a10 0x10031f2e8 0x100315634 0x100321630 0x10032139c 0x185b631d0 0x185b62d7c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My processedImage comes out to be nil. I am using ARC so I am not handling any releasing. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong and if you could point me towards some examples and information on using the filters, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My code was missing

```
[subFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
```

before attaining output of the two images. The same type of example can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30730364/5071756